# Error Propagation in Keras DNN and/or CNN Regression

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Using Keras with Tensorflow as the backend, I have created both a CNN and DNN to predict three stellar parameters (Temperature, gravity, and metallicity) using the stellar spectra as an input. Both models predict very well when applied to test sets, but in order to make my results useful it is necessary to include errors in my predictions.

The input spectra each have 7000 data points and the output is 3 values. Each spectra also has an error array of 7000 data points that I would like to be able to propagate through my model so that there is a set of 3 uncertainties associated with each prediction. Does anyone have any experience or insight on how to accomplish this?

My DNN structure looks something like this:

```
# Define vars
activation = 'relu'
init = 'he_normal'
beta_1 = 0.9
beta_2 = 0.999
epsilon = 1e-08
input_shape = (None,7000)

epochs = 100
lr = 0.0009
batch_size = 64
n_hidden = [2048,1024,512,256,128]

# Design DNN Layers

model = Sequential([

    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=input_shape),

    Dense(n_hidden[0], init=init, activation=activation, bias=True),


    Dense(n_hidden[1], init=init, activation=activation, bias=True), 

    Dense(n_hidden[2], init=init, activation=activation, bias=True),

    Dense(n_hidden[3], init=init, activation=activation, bias=True),

    Dense(n_hidden[4], init=init, activation=activation, bias=True),

    Dense(l, init=init, activation='linear', bias=True),
])



# Optimization function
optimizer = Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon, decay=0.0)


# Compile and train network
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001, 
                           patience=3, verbose=2, mode='min')


## train_X.shape = (50000,7000)
## train_Y.shape = (50000,3)
## cv_X.shape = (10000,7000)
## cv_Y.shape = (10000,3)

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(cv_X, cv_Y),
             nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

My CNN is somewhat similar; basically replacing the first few layers with 1D-CNN layers and modifying the number of filters and filter lengths. Any thoughts on how to propagate errors through the model. I am familiar with some methods of obtaining the error of the model (through multiple trainings of the same model and/or dropout layers), but what I am looking for are errors in the actual predictions.

**EDIT**

Here is the architecture for my CNN

```
# Define vars
input_shape = (None,7000,1)
epochs = 30
activation = 'relu'
initializer = 'he_normal'
beta_1 = 0.9
beta_2 = 0.999
epsilon = 1e-08
batch_size = 64


n_hidden = [1024,512,256]
n_filters = [16,32,32,64,64]
lr = 0.001




model = Sequential([
    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=input_shape),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[0], filter_length=8, activation=activation, border_mode='same', init=initializer, input_shape=input_shape),
    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[1], filter_length=8, activation=activation, border_mode='same', init=initializer), 
    MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[2], filter_length=8, activation=activation, border_mode='same', init=initializer),
    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[3], filter_length=8, activation=activation, border_mode='same', init=initializer),
    MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[4], filter_length=10, activation=activation),
    MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4),
    Flatten(),

    Dense(output_dim=n_hidden[0], activation=activation, init=initializer),
    Dense(output_dim=n_hidden[1], activation=activation, init=initializer),
    Dense(output_dim=n_hidden[2], activation=activation, init=initializer),

    Dense(output_dim=l, input_dim=n_hidden[2], activation='linear'),
])




# Compile Model
optimizer=Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=epsilon, decay=0.0)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001, 
                           patience=3, verbose=2, mode='min')

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(cv_X, cv_Y),
                nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Comment: So I understand that you want to predict uncertainties. Do you have training data for those uncertainties?

Comment: Yes, each spectrum that consists of 7000 data points also has an error spectrum which also consists of 7000 data points. Currently I have trained a model on 50,000 spectra but have not taken into account the error spectra. The model has trained really well so far, but in order for the results to be scientifically useful, I need to propagate the error spectra through the model somehow and have 3 resulting error values that correspond to the 3 predicted values. Any ideas?

Comment: The error spectrum of 7000 data points describes the errors/uncertainties on the input side, whereas you want to predict uncertainties in the 3 output parameters. So, I was asking if you have any data which describes how the error spectrum affects the output parameters. In short, you also need some data about the uncertainties of those 3 parameters. From what you have described till now, I don't think you have that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have errors in the 3 target parameters for each spectrum as well if that is what you are asking.

Comment: You can build a Siamese network which has two channels and their weights are shared. Each channel can follow the same architecture as your CNN/DNN. One channel will take the input spectrum and predict output parameters, other channel will take the input error spectrum and predict output errors. See [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py) for more information on how to build a Siamese network.

Comment: Ahh that's pretty neat. I will definitely give this a try. Have you heard of error propagation being used in Deep Neural Networks before? It would be treating the model weights as a function and at every step where a weight is applied to an input, the error associated with that input is modified depending on the function being applied. And in the end you are left with - in our case - 3 errors. Some simple error propagations are explained here: 

http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm

I just haven't come across this type of error propagation in DNNs

Comment: this answer may come a bit late. However, we recently published our work on error propagation in large-scale neural networks for sampling-free uncertainty at ICCV (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00598.pdf). We also provide the code for our experiments (https://github.com/janisgp/Sampling-free-Epistemic-Uncertainty), where you can find out how to use keras with tensorflow to perform **large-scale error propagation through a neural network**.